# Как сделать так, чтобы файл (например, .txt) нельзя было открыть для записи?

Tags: c#

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил данные в программе, и она записывала их в файл, т.е через программу доступ к файлу был, но, если пользователь самостоятельно откроет файл, то этот файл будет открыт только для чтения. Пока формулировал вопрос, появилась идея, как это сделать:
В программе меняю доступ к файлу, разрешаю запись, записываю мои данные и снова запрещаю запись. В итоге пользователь может самостоятельно открыть файл только для чтения. 
Логика такая, верно?

Comment: Что мешает пользователю изменить права доступа?

Comment: @froxxendsg по задумке большей части пользователей вообще не нужно открывать этот файл. Сам файл находится в папке общего доступа, и, если он будет открыт у кого-нибудь из пользователей (вдруг он откроет его, чтобы посмотреть, что там, и забудет закрыть?), то с записью в файл будут некоторые проблемы. Пользователя по умолчанию считаем человеком, который никакие действия, кроме тех, что необходимо сделать в программе, выполнять не будет

Comment: Чтобы нерадивые пользователи не лазили в файлы настроек и не ломали там ничего своими кривыми ручками, нужно делать эти файлы бинарными или сжатыми, или шифрованными.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov увы, данные из этого файла нужно будет редактировать/копировать еще одному неопределенному кругу пользователей. Т.е есть 2 группы пользователей, их количество неизвестно и они могут меняться (т.е если делать так "эти пользователи могут открывать файл", то необходимо будет поддерживать актуальный список пользователей с доступом). Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы у программы было как можно меньше шансов выдать сообщение "запись не удалась, т.к файл открыт у другого пользователя"

Answer (score 4):

Вообще приложение не обладает никакими привилегиями по отношению к файлам. Привилегиями обладает лишь пользователь ОС. Поэтому когда вы запускаете приложение, оно может делать с файлом ровно то же самое, что и текущий пользователь, от лица которого запущено приложение.

Поэтому, чтобы приложению дать больше привилегий для работы с файлом, чем пользователю - необходимо **запускать его от лица другого пользователя.**  Для этого в исполняемый файл нужно [встроить манифест приложения](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)). Но при запуске такого приложения будет выскакивать окно UAC (контроля учетных записей). И его никак уже невозможно обойти.

Ответ переведен. Ссылка на оригинальный ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16313478/6468198).

Answer (score -1):

Можно поступить как Microsoft. Если ваша программа работает под линукс, то на время выполнения переименовывать читаемый файл как скрытый `filename.txt` -> `.filename.txt` 
Если же под Windows то аналогично выставить ему аттрибут `скрытый`